# Twitter style flat list in long list selector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, longlistselector

I am trying to create an Windows Phone 8 app that will display information in small horizontal blocks, similar to how Twitter displays tweets in a rectangle box per tweet and you can scroll through the list.

I think I can do something similar with the LongListSelector in Windows Phone 8 and a flat list but I am struggling to understand it.

I am currently storing the data I want to use in a class similar to this:

```C#
public class DataFromWebSite
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

For each entry that is going into the list, there will be the 4 items above.  So each item/entry would be something like this, with each of these items appearing in one entry:

```
Name - Joe Bloggs    Country - Vulcan
Age - 99             Telephone - 123456789
```

I'm not sure if a flat long-list selector is the way to go here and if so, how to implement it.  Or whether I should just go for a plain list box and try to add the items and format them to make them easier to read with line breaks etc.

Here's my code and my XAML.

```C#
flightDetails.Add(new flightContainer
{
    Origin = origin,
    Airline = airline,
    FlightNumber = flightNumber,
    Due = due,
    Status = status
});

lstFlights.ItemsSource = flightDetails;
```

XAML

```XAML
<ListBox Margin="0,10" Name="lstFlights" SelectionChanged="flightSelection" FontSize="18" >               
    <ListBox.Items>

    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You're missing a XAML template for each item. Right now, it renders each item with the default behavior of calling ToString() on it, which is why you get the class name. Look at this simple example: http://abundantcode.com/displaying-data-in-flat-list-in-windows-phone-8-longlistselector-control/.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you define your ListItemTemplate. You can arrange your elements in the ListItemTemplate the way you want. If you want to just display, LongListSelector might be a heavy control to use. Just ListBox would be enough. Even ListBox has ListItemTemplate.

A good tutorial on ListBox: http://mobileosgeek.com/how-to-bind-data-to-listbox-in-windows-phone/

A good tutorial on LongListSelector: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Comment: Thanks, I think I am doing something stupid though.  This is my current code:

    var flightDetails = new ObservableCollection<flightContainer>();

    flightDetails.Add(new flightContainer
    {
         Origin = origin,
         Airline = airline,
         FlightNumber = flightNumber,
         Due = due,
         Status = status
     });

    lstFlights.ItemsSource = flightDetails;

But when I run the app, all that gets added to the listbox is:

projectName:flightContainer

And not the actual values.

Comment: update your question with this code and your xaml. This should be pretty straight forward. Sounds like your bindings might be screwy.

Comment: See you are missing your ListItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are asking but I would recommend going to **Blend** and editing your item template.  In Blend you just find the control and right click and edit the templates you need.